# How do I return an object of word and its length from an array of words?

Tags: javascript

Given an array of strings, return an object
containing a key for every different string in the array,
and the value is that string's length.

```
wordLen(["a", "bb", "a", "bb"])          → { "bb": 2, "a": 1 }
wordLen(["this", "and", "that", "and"])  → { "that": 4, "and": 3, "this": 4 }
wordLen(["code", "code", "code", "bug"]) → { "code": 4, "bug": 3 }
```

Comment: looks like a homework question to me.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you blocked?

Answer (score 1):

```js
var arr = ["a", "bb", "a", "bb"];
var entries = arr.map(x => [x, x.length]);
console.log(Object.fromEntries(entries));
```

Comment: `const wordLen = arr => arr.reduce((r,w)=>(r[w] ??= w.length,r),{})`

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the array and store each word length in an object with the word itself being the key

```js
function wordLen(arr){
    let words = {};
    arr.forEach(word => words[word] = word.length);
    return words;
}
```

Non-ES6

```js
function wordLen(arr){
    var words = {};
    arr.forEach(function(word){ words[word] = word.length });
    return words;
}
```